# Matplotlib нарисовать 1 точку на заданной по размерам сетке

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

мне нужно нарисовать 1 точку на сетке с заданными интервалами по x и y. То есть у меня есть диапазон на котором выпадают точки, это y=[1,16], x=[1,16]. Мне нужно нарисовать 1 точку + сетку на заданных интервалах. Может ли кто-нибудь подсказать решение.
Я пробовал такой способ

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw={'xticks': [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16],
                                           'yticks': [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12,14,16]})
        ax.scatter(4,8)
        ax.grid(axis = 'both')
```

но при таком подходе просто рисует точку без грида, я пробовал тоже самое, но с пустым конструктором subplot-а, тогда грид рисуется, но понятное дело без интервалов.

Comment: покажите пожалуйста что у вас есть, т.е. что вы пробовали.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/8209568

Comment: это не совсем то, что требуется, я попробовал ax.set_xticks(np.arange(0, 17, 1)), но этот метод работает только когда строишь несколько точек, а для одной точки выводится просто точка, и под ней её координаты, а самой сетки нет.

Answer (score 1):

Как то так путано вы излагаете, что что-либо уразуметь крайне трудно.

Итак проблема: надо нарисовать ОДНУ точку. При этом на рисунке должна быть сетка. При этом пределы по Х и Y заданы явно. Правильно?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)
ax.scatter(4,8)
ax.set_xlim([0, 10])
ax.set_ylim([0, 10])
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(2))
ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(2))
ax.grid()
```

Имеем:

Если вы что-то другое имели ввиду - уточняйте вопрос.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]